# Cannot remove Chrome from dock

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

I cannot remove Google Chrome from the dock. I have a MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) running macOs Monterey 12.4.

There is no remove from dock option and dragging it away doesn't work either. I also want to delete it so I did, and shortly after it got removed from the dock. However, after restarting or logging out and in again, it is back again, showing a question mark because it can't find the app.

I found out that the dock stuff was stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist`, so I deleted it for it to revert to the original order, but since Google Chrome is also in that original order, that wouldn't work.
I could perfectly well remove other apps from the dock (except for Finder obviously and Safari, strangely), but not Google Chrome.

How would I remove Google Chrome from the dock and save that change after restarts or logging out and in again, and also delete it?

EDIT-
There's a fix involving Managed Preferences but I don't have that folder

Comment: Do [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376273/os-x-dock-wont-let-me-remove-icons) help?

Comment: @ServiceDeskBunny Sadly, no. There is no 'Managed Preferences' Folder